Phantom support of wallet-standard encrypt/decrypt
There are two experimental interfaces in wallet-standard for encryption/decryption of arbitrary data using the ed25519 key pairs.
https://github.com/wallet-standard/wallet-standard/blob/master/packages/experimental/features/src/encrypt.ts
https://github.com/wallet-standard/wallet-standard/blob/master/packages/experimental/features/src/decrypt.ts
Is there a plan for Phantom to support these two via wallet-adapters?
Same question posted at https://github.com/orgs/phantom/discussions/252

Voting to close this not because it's a bad question, but because this is 100% in the hands of Phantom and not Solana. I'd recommend asking this to Phantom directly, but you're already doing that :)
